# Replace parenthesis and brackets in string

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a regexp that replaces all brackets and parenthesis and the Content between a pair in a String.

I use `regexp_replace(str_col, '\[(.*?)\]')` with Amazon redshift, but this only replaces parenthesis, Not the Content within.

Comment: Try `regexp_replace(str_col, '\\[[^]]*]')`. Could you please provide an example text with the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Amazon Redshift [supports only POSIX regex](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html), you need to use

1) To remove all `[...]` strings:

```
regexp_replace(str_col, '\\[[^]]*]')
```

2) To remove all `(...)` strings:

```
regexp_replace(str_col, '\\([^)]*\\)')
```

3) To remove both:

```
regexp_replace(str_col, '\\[[^]]*]|\\([^)]*\\)')
```